# PHP - monster avatar generator

Tags: php, avatar-generation

I have seen a avatar generator which makes monster creators, but I saw this a few years ago and now can't remember the name or find it with Google. Does anyone have a url?

Comment: Do you remember more details? A cursory search turns up http://monster.namedecoder.com/, but I assume you must've saw this already.

Comment: @TNi - I don't remember much, the only thing I remember is that it only generated a face, not whole body, and it was used to give an avatar to commentators on a blog. The url you mentioned is unfortunately filtered by our big brother (don't know why), will check with a vpn to see if it is what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @TNi - Ha ha! That is interesting too, although not what I was looking for. It says I am a `Malevolent, Abhorrent, Jogger-Injuring Demon`!

Comment: this is a site focused on software development. this kind of question should be googled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're thinking of [MonsterID](http://www.splitbrain.org/projects/monsterid)

> MonsterID is a method to generate a
>   unique monster image based upon a
>   certain identifier (IP address, email
>   address, whatever). It can be used to
>   automatically provide personal avatar
>   images in blog comments or other
>   community services.
>
> The download contains a PHP file which
>   will generate a random monster by
>   default. When given a seed request
>   parameter the monster will be based on
>   this parameter and will always be the
>   same for the same parameter. A second
>   optional parameter named size can be
>   given to get a resized image.